# NSTableView not responding to reloadData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm having problems reloading data into an NSTableView. The variable I'm using as IBOutlet is always Null. The table itself works fine, since the dummy object is loaded during awakefromnib without problems. The 2 mandatory methods also work since they are executed both during awakefromnib. Unfortunatelly the outlet is null and the reloaddata method is not working....

```
@implementation TableViewControllore
-(void) awakeFromNib{
clip *clipDummy=[[clip alloc]init];

[clipDummy setNomeClip:@"dummy"];
[clipDummy setTcIn:@"10:00:00:00"];
[clipDummy setTcOut:@"10:00:00:10"];
[clipDummy setClipPath:@"volumes"];
[clipArray addObject:clipDummy];
[clipDummy release];
}

-(id) init{
    self =[super init];
    if (self){
        clipArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
return self;

}

-(void) addClip : (clip*) myclip{
[clipArray addObject:myclip];
[tableView1 reloadData];
}

- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *) aTableView{
return [clipArray count];
}
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn*)aTableColumn row:(int)rowIndex{
    clip *c= [clipArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    NSString *identifier=[aTableColumn identifier];
    return [c valueForKey:identifier];
}

@end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? How often is `numberOfRowsInTableView` and `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:` called? Have you verified that tableView1 is not nil?

Comment: By the way: You may just access the tableView by calling `self.tableView`: http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: numberOfRowsInTableView and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn: are only called once when the table is loaded. the debugger is not reporting nil for tableView1 but 0x0...UITableView works like NSTableview?

Comment: ok. I have summarized the issue in my answer!

Comment: what variable name you used for IBOutlet. It MUST not be 0. Make sure that you connect the outlet properly from XIB to file owner.